# not only numbers regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression that allows letters (English and Arabic) with numbers, but not only numbers, also allows punctuates, spaces and multi-line(\n), when i searched i found this one
   `(?!^\d+$)^.+$` 
that doesn't allow multi-line.
i tried to write my own which is 
    `(([a-zA-Zء-ي\s:-])|([0-9]+[a-zA-Zء-ي\s:-])|([a-zA-Zء-ي\s:-]+[0-9]$))*`
the problem of that is :
 1. it doesn't accept a number as end of string as employer9 but if it was employer9+"space" it workes fine.
 2. i have to write every punctuates that is allowed, is their is a way easier to do this?

Comment: What is _not_ allowed then? Seems to me that making sure things that aren't allowed aren't there is easier.

Comment: not only numbers e.g **01236445**

Comment: If you're just looking for *not numbers*, why not just check if this: `^[0-9]+$` is not a match?

Comment: You need to describe more clearly (maybe with a couple of examples) what kinds of things are NOT allowed. I think (based on my current understanding of your question) that @SpikeX has nailed it; can you clarify? Three strings that are good, and three strings that are bad, would be very helpful to fine-tune an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use `DOTALL` or the `s` modifier for the regex.  You could do this with:

```
(?s)(?!^\d+$)^.+$
```

...or you could use the compiler flags when constructing the regex.

An alternative not using `DOTALL` would be:

```
(?!^\d+$)^[\s\S]+$
```